# String to Integer Smalltalk

Tags: string, integer, type-conversion, smalltalk

Pretty simple question I need to get an integer from the user and I only know how to get a string from them. So if there is a way to get an integer from the user or to convert the string to an integer please let me know.

Comment: Just make up a random int; users rarely know what they want anyway!!! (joke)

Comment: No, it must always be the number 7 on Friday, but it can be random numbers any other day, unless it's the fourth Wednesday of the Month and it is cloudy outside, in which case it should be 42.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it:

```
'12345' asNumber.
```

Comment: That's weird, asNumber can't handle radix syntax: `'16r12345' asNumber -> 16`. How do you supply a base?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Squeak or Pharo, learn to use the "Message Finder".

Left click on the background, click Tools > Message Finder. Click on the top left pane. Type:

```
'12345'. 12345.
```

Hit Control-S and you have your answer. Specifically, you have three answers: **asInteger**, **asNumber** and **initialIntegerOrNil**.

Comment: If you're not using Squeak or Pharo, why not, and do you then realize you need to specify your dialect?

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.angelfire.com/tx4/cus/notes/smalltalk.html) seems to have some conversion examples. Search for `Conversion:`.

**UPDATE**

Try using `asNumber`

Comment: i cant find string to integer on that page and i've seen it before. I'll keep looking at it.

Comment: asNumber was not on that page.

Comment: Ah, looks like you figured it out :)

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally you'll want to handle numbers in different bases.

```
st> s := '3039'.
'3039'
st> Number readFrom: (ReadStream on: s) radix: 16.
12345
```

Comment: Number readFrom: '16rff' => 255. In Squeak, and almost certainly in Pharo.