# string to integer in smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk

i want to convert the input value in "Prompter prompt: aStringPrompt" into a integer value, how can i do that?

Comment: After posting my answer, I notice that this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226029

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Integer Smalltalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226029/string-to-integer-smalltalk)

Answer (score 5):

Two steps: (a) validate the input, and (b) convert.

You could validate like so: `myString isAllDigits`.

Converting is trivial: `'1' asInteger`. In Squeak, at least, this returns the integer 1. `'g1' asInteger` returns 1, as does `'g1' asInteger`. `g asInteger` returns nil.

So in summary:

```
"Given some input string s containing a decimal representation of a number, either return s in integer form, or raise an exception."
s := self getUserInput.
(s isAllDigits) ifFalse: [ Exception signal: '"', s, '" is not a (decimal) number' ].

^ s asInteger.
```

Comment: sir how about in dolphin, i don't use squeak. can you explain it in dolphin syntax? thanks a lot

Comment: aString asInteger should work in all Smalltalks. The best way is to experiment a bit and look at the class library of your Smalltalk dialect to find out all possibilities.

Comment: @Frank Shearar, thanks for the link but i that still did solve my problem. after the input dialog box appeared i entered my number but it doesn't change it to asInteger or to asNumber variable. my problem is after i declare my random number it doesn't change it here is my code please comment on it if you have a idea on how to solve it thank you

Comment: | dir |

[ dir isNil or: [dir isEmpty]] whileTrue:

[ dir:= Prompter prompt: 'Enter your number' caption:'Input the Number' ].


MessageBox notify: 'your inputed number is ', (dir) caption: 'Inputed'.

i want to make a simple "Guess the Number game" but for starters i want to convert the user input to anInterger type but it always have an error after i input my random number, i tried everything from asInteger, asNumber and nothing.. please help (in this program it only copies what i entered)

Comment: says does not understand #number, i don't remember much cause i forgot to save it

Answer (score 1):

Just tried this in Dolphin 6:

```
(Prompter prompt: 'Enter a number') asInteger
```

Run this (place cursor on the above in a workspace and hit Ctrl-D), enter 123 in the prompt that comes up, and you'll see 123 displayed as the output.  If you remove the #asInteger invocation, it'll display '123', indicating that a String was returned.

As to your 'does not understand #number', that means that somewhere in the code you were running the message #number as being sent to an object that didn't know how to handle it.

For the fun of it I took your code and slightly reformatted it:

```
| dir |

[ dir isNil or: [ dir isEmpty ] ] whileTrue:
    [ dir:= Prompter prompt: 'Enter your number' caption: 'Input the Number' ].

MessageBox notify: 'your inputed number is ', (dir) caption: 'Inputed'.
```

and found that it ran just fine.  Then I noticed it didn't convert the returned String to a number, so I changed it to:

```
| dir |

[ ( dir isNil or: [ dir isEmpty ] ) or: [ (dir select: [ :c | c isDigit not ]) size > 0 ] ]  whileTrue:
    [ dir:= Prompter prompt: 'Enter your number' caption: 'Input the Number' ].

MessageBox notify: 'your inputed number is ', (dir) caption: 'Inputed'.
```

This also ran fine, with the added benefit that it won't accept non-numeric characters.

Share and enjoy.